# How do I disable future dates in react js or Vanilla or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, javascript-objects, vanilla-forums

I have two drop down

1. It only has years which is restricted to last 7 years from present year (Working fine)
2. It only has months which should show the months till present month only

for Example
if we today date is  (15 march 2023) then the drop down should show
Year - 2023 and
Month drop down should show value from Jan to March (Future months should be restricted)
(but now it is showing all months)

[image]

Now the code for year is as follow

```
  const minAppDate = new Date(
  new Date().getFullYear() - 7,
  new Date().getMonth(),
  new Date().getDate()
);
const maxAppDate = new Date(
  new Date().getFullYear(),
  new Date().getMonth() - 1
);
    const range = (start, stop, step = 1) => {
  if (typeof stop === 'undefined') {
    // One param defined
    stop = start;
    start = 0;
  }

  if ((step > 0 && start >= stop) || (step < 0 && start <= stop)) {
    return [];
  }

  const result = [];
  for (let i = start; step > 0 ? i < stop : i > stop; i += step) {
    result.push(i);
  }

  return result;
};
const years = range(minAppDate.getFullYear(), maxAppDate.getFullYear() + 1).map(
  year => ({
    label: year,
    value: year
  })
);
```

the value is getting stored in Year

similary i am doing for month

```
months: [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
  ]

const months = months.map((month, index) => ({
  label: month,
  value: index < 9 ? '0' + (index + 1) : index + 1
}));
```

after that i am passing the values in DropDown options

```
<Dropdown
              required
              id='year'
              options={years}
              label='Year'
              name='year'
              value={values.year}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

so i want to send the option before only can any one let me know what i am doing wrong